# printf, translation and the_author_posts_link()

Tags: templates, author, front-end

For some reason the following code is not displaying correctly on the frontend of my site -

```
<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'About %s', 'textdomain' ), the_author_posts_link() ); ?>
```

Instead of displaying the translatable string 'About' before the author's name/link, it's displaying it afterwards. I assume this is because I'm using a function in there instead of a variable.

Is there a way to make this work or should I completely re-write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_author_posts_link` "Displays a link to all posts by an author."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link) That is, the function `echo`s content. It does not return the content for use by some other function.

You won't be able to use that function, but you should be able to [use it as a model for your own function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/author-template.php#L194) for generating and `return`ing the link instead of `echo`ing it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I temporarily got around the issue by using get_author_posts_url in an html link tag. But I think I'll write my own function based upon the WP the_author_posts_link() to do exactly what I want because it should be a cleaner solution.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
esc_attr_e( 'About', 'textdomain' );
echo ' ';
the_author_posts_link();
```

[`esc_attr_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr_e) echos the escaped text.